# how do I center align a content element with wordpress custom css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am attempting to center align an image carousel in a wordpress webpage. I tried this line of code in Custom CSS from the panel menu and it did not work for me:

.cleaning_carousel {width: 50% !important; margin: 0px auto !important;}

To see the site in question, visit https://livingwatersict.com/ponds/

Can someone point out the mistakes that I am making?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this make an outer div and use css `text-align:center`

```css
.outer
{
text-align:center;
}
.inner
{
width:300px;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

<img src="http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/attachments/travelogues/412228d1282577980-taj-mahal-full-moon-fatehpur-sikri-mathura-bharatpur-keoladeo-national-park-img_9119_20_21_tonemappedb.jpg" class="inner">

</div>
```